# How to load data into Product case class using Dataframe in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a text file and has data like below:

```
productId|price|saleEvent|rivalName|fetchTS 
123|78.73|Special|VistaCart.com|2017-05-11 15:39:30 
123|45.52|Regular|ShopYourWay.com|2017-05-11 16:09:43 
123|89.52|Sale|MarketPlace.com|2017-05-11 16:07:29 
678|1348.73|Regular|VistaCart.com|2017-05-11 15:58:06 
678|1348.73|Special|ShopYourWay.com|2017-05-11 15:44:22 
678|1232.29|Daily|MarketPlace.com|2017-05-11 15:53:03 
777|908.57|Daily|VistaCart.com|2017-05-11 15:39:01
```

I have to find minimum price of a product across websites, e.g. my output should be like this:

```
productId|price|saleEvent|rivalName|fetchTS 
123|45.52|Regular|ShopYourWay.com|2017-05-11 16:09:43 
678|1232.29|Daily|MarketPlace.com|2017-05-11 15:53:03 
777|908.57|Daily|VistaCart.com|2017-05-11 15:39:01
```

I am trying like this:

```
case class Product(productId:String, price:Double, saleEvent:String, rivalName:String, fetchTS:String)

val cDF = spark.read.text("/home/prabhat/Documents/Spark/sampledata/competitor_data.txt")
val (header,values) = cDF.collect.splitAt(1)
values.foreach(x => Product(x(0).toString, x(1).toString.toDouble, 
x(2).toString, x(3).toString, x(4).toString))
```

Getting exception while running last line:

```
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow
 .get(rows.scala:174)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.apply(Row.scala:163)
 at 
 org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow
 .apply(rows.scala:166
 )
 at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:28)
 at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:28)
 at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach
 (IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
 at 
 scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
 ... 49 elided
```

Priting value in **values**:

```
scala> values
res2: **Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]** = ` 
Array([123|78.73|Special|VistaCart.com|2017-05-11 15:39:30 ], 
[123|45.52|Regular|ShopYourWay.com|2017-05-11 16:09:43 ], 
[123|89.52|Sale|MarketPlace.com|2017-05-11 16:07:29 ], 
[678|1348.73|Regular|VistaCart.com|2017-05-11 15:58:06 ], 
[678|1348.73|Special|ShopYourWay.com|2017-05-11 15:44:22 ], 
[678|1232.29|Daily|MarketPlace.com|2017-05-11 15:53:03 ], 
[777|908.57|Daily|VistaCart.com|2017-05-11 15:39:01 ]`
scala>
```

I am able to understand that I need to `split("|")`.

```
scala> val xy = values.foreach(x => x.toString.split("|").toSeq)
xy: Unit = ()
```

So after splitting its giving me `Unit` class, i.e. void, so unable to load **values** into the `Product` case class. How can I load this Dataframe to `Product` case class? I dont want to use Dataset for now, although Dataset is type safe.

I'm using Spark 2.3 and Scala 2.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to `split` taking a regex, which means you need to use `"\\|"` instead of a single `"|"`. Also, the `foreach` need to be changed to `map` to actually give a return value, i.e:

```
val xy = values.map(x => x.toString.split("\\|"))
```

---

However, a better approach would be to read the data as a csv file with `|` separators. In this way you do not need to treat the header in a special way and by inferring the column types there is no need to make any convertions (here I changed `fetchTS` to a timestamp):

```
case class Product(productId: String, price: Double, saleEvent: String, rivalName: String, fetchTS: Timestamp)

val df = spark.read
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .option("sep", "|")
  .csv("/home/prabhat/Documents/Spark/sampledata/competitor_data.txt")
  .as[Product]
```

The final line will convert the dataframe to use the `Product` case class. If you want to use it as an RDD instead, simply add `.rdd` in the end.

After this is done, use `groupBy` and `agg` to get the final results.